# Conflicts between installed library and my code due to compiler variation on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang

I am using c++ to develop my software on ArchLinux.

If I install a library, for example, `libffmpeg`, from the official source, such as `apt` on Ubuntu, `pacman` on Archlinux.

However, in my project, I use `clang` as the compiler.

My question is:

1. Which compiler does the official package use? Do I have to use the same compiler?
   For example, the official package uses `gcc`, so that I have to use `gcc` instead of `clang`.
2. If I have to use the same compiler, `gcc`, do I have to use the same version? For example, the official package uses `gcc9`, do I have to use `gcc9`? Can I use `gcc8`?

/*******************************************************************************/

Recently when I compile my code, I found there is an error:

```
undefined reference to 
`std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
```

It seems that it cannot find `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream`. I searched on the Internet and find from `gcc5` it has a new feature. I have to use

```
//CMakeLists.txt
add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` file.
But it doesn't work.

Is it because I use a different compiler version?

Comment: Did you install the C++ standard library and did you tell clang where to look for it?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I did.
Even I use gcc8, it is not compatible. My archlinux's default compiler is gcc9.

Comment: Clang has supported modern c++ features far before gcc. So if you have at least clang5 installed, libstdc++ and you tell the compiler where to find it you should be fine. The compiler uses environment variables and such so male sure those are all right.

Comment: Compilers turn your code into machine code for your architecture. As long as the compilers support those specific sets of features you can compile. You didn't even post your code. How do we know you just didn't forget an include or something or changed the linker path. We wouldn't know.